# glColor doesn't change the color of other triangles in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

So I am still a newbie with opengl and I used this tutorial as a reference

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8p76pJsUP44

I am now trying to draw a set of 4 triangles that made up a square (it's my project assignment) and this is my code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void changeViewPort(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}


void draw() {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 255.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // top triangle
        glVertex3f(-1.0,1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        glColor3f(50.0, 50.0, 255.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // right triangle
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);

        glColor3f(75.0, 75.0, 255.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);//bottom triangle
        glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);

        glColor3f(50.0, 50.0, 255.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //left triangle
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glEnd();
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    draw();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // Set up some memory buffers for our display
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    // Set the window size
    glutInitWindowSize(350, 300);
    // Create the window with the title "Hello,GL"
    glutCreateWindow("Hello, GL");
    // Bind the two functions (above) to respond when necessary
    glutReshapeFunc(changeViewPort);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    //glutDisplayFunc(draw);

    // Very important!  This initializes the entry points in the OpenGL driver so we can 
    // call all the functions in the API.
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW error");
        return 1;
    }


    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

notice that in my draw function, I am just trying to create 4 different triangles with different shades of blue.
However, whenever this code is executed, only the top triangle is blue while the rest stays white

Does anyone know why this wouldnt work ? I even tried to create a for loop version of the draw function but it also didnt work

```
void draw() {
    double x = 1.0;
    double y = 1.0;
    double coords[8] = { -x,y,x,y,x,-y,-x,-y };

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i=i+2) { // i = [0,2,4,6]
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            glColor3f(0, 0, 255);
            break;
        case 2:
            glColor3f(50, 50, 255);
            break;
        case 4:
            glColor3f(75, 75, 255);
            break;
        case 6:
            glColor3f(50, 50, 255);
            break;
        }

        if (i == 6) { //4th and 1st coordinate
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(coords[i], coords[i + 1], 0.0);
            glVertex3f(coords[0], coords[1], 0.0);
            glEnd();
        }
        else {
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(coords[i], coords[i + 1], 0.0);
            glVertex3f(coords[i + 2], coords[i + 3], 0.0);
            glEnd();
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

`glColor3f` takes color components in the [0, 1] range as input and not [0, 255] as currently used.

Answer (score 2):

Colors in OpenGL are stored in [0, 1] range. Unsigned ints map onto that range linearly automatically, but floats are just straight up stored.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318399(v=vs.85).aspx